# next() call in middleware of mounted apps in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express application:

```
var site = new express();
```

Then I make the admin part a sub app:

```
var admin = new express();
admin.get("/users", function(req, res) {...});
```

Finally I mount admin app onto the main site with a permission checking middleware:

```
var isAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user.admin) {
        return res.send("403");
    }
    next();
};

site.use("/admin", isAdmin, admin);
```

Problem is: when I open `/admin/users` page, the `next()` call in permission checking leads to a 404 in the end. I feel it calls the next callback function in *site* instead of going into *admin*.

If I remove the permission checking middleware, write just like this:

```
site.use("/admin", admin);
```

Then `/admin/users` can be accessed finely. Without any ACL of course...

Question is How can I make the code goes into *admin* sub app in the middleware chain?

Answer (score 0):

Well... right after I posted this question I realised my code should be like this:

```
var site = new express();

var admin = new express();

var isAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user.admin) {
        return res.send("403");
    }
    next();
};

admin.use(isAdmin);
admin.get("/users", function(req, res) {...});

site.use("/admin", isAdmin, admin);
```

The difference is `isAdmin` is applied to the sub app now. This works well.